# Not clearing FBO's Texture error in battery economy mode

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, gpu, frame-buffer

When rendering inside a FBO's texture, I'm not using *glClear*() but overwriting each fragment, *GL_BLEND* is set to *true*.

This works just fine, but  I just realised when my laptop switch to economy mode, and I guess switch to egpu (intel 630) , the texture is full of garbage data when drawn.

here you can see first the working render, and then the garbage one. It should be exactly the same the only difference is my laptop is not plugged in AC

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug to log to Intel about their graphics driver.

Comment: I have the same problem on AMD Vega 8 graphics, wich is the hardware I need to use, but no problem on NVIDIA GTX1060, 2 againt one, I'm guessing something in my code. I'm wondering if this is not my problem, and if writting to a PBO instead would solve my problem

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, when something works on NVidia but fails on AMD or Intel, it usually means that you're doing something subtly wrong and NVidia is fixing it for you behind the scenes or otherwise letting you get away with it.  Both Intel and especially AMD are known to be absolute sticklers for strongly obeying the OpenGL specifications, where NVidia drivers/hardware will often silently cope with a lot of issues.

Comment: @TrevorPowell thanks for your answer, if NVidia is fixing, then there must be somthing I can do to , by adding some lines to my code or extensions ?